# Unable to build LLVM on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: build, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

I am trying to build `release/16.x` of `llvm-project`; but hitting a snafu:

First things first, the system I am on is as follows

```
Inside my Oracle VirtualBox 7.0, I have
RAM: 5 GiB
CPU: 3 x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Clang: Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1
CMake: cmake version 3.22.1
Ninja: 1.10.1
Gold: GNU gold (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu 2.38) 1.16
Python: Python 3.10
```

After cloning the `release/16.x` branch, I am using the following configuration:

```bash
mkdir -p build; mkdir -p installed; cd build; \
cmake -G "Ninja" \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$(which clang) \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$(which clang++) \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld" \
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;RISCV" \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON \
-DLLVM_PARALLEL_COMPILE_JOBS=2 \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(pwd)/../installed \
-DLLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS=2 \
-DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=ON \
-DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=ON \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
-DLLVM_USE_SPLIT_DWARF=ON \
-DLLVM_USE_LINKER=gold \
-DLLVM_OPTIMIZED_TABLEGEN=ON \
-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS='-Wl,-no-keep-memory,-fuse-ld=gold' \
../llvm
```

The `cmake` configuration completes successfully, and build files are written:

```bash
...
...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /media/sf_shared_folder/myProject/llvm-project/build
```

Subsequently, when I am trying to build the project using `ninja`, I am facing the following problem:

```bash
ninja -j2 all
[243/3771] Building native llvm-tblgen...
[236/236] Linking CXX executable bin/llvm-tblgen
[326/3771] Building Attributes.inc...
FAILED: include/llvm/IR/Attributes.inc /media/sf_shared_folder/myProject/llvm-project/build/include/llvm/IR/Attributes.inc 
cd /media/sf_shared_folder/myProject/llvm-project/build && /media/sf_shared_folder/myProject/llvm-project/build/NATIVE/bin/llvm-tblgen -gen-attrs -I /media/sf_shared_folder/myProject/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR -I/media/sf_shared_folder/myProject/llvm-project/build/include -I/media/sf_shared_folder/myProject/llvm-project/llvm/include /media/sf_shared_folder/myProject/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Attributes.td --write-if-changed -o include/llvm/IR/Attributes.inc -d include/llvm/IR/Attributes.inc.d
/bin/sh: 1: /media/sf_shared_folder/myProject/llvm-project/build/NATIVE/bin/llvm-tblgen: Exec format error
[327/3771] Building CXX object tools/clang/utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/clang-tblgen.dir/ClangAttrEmitter.cpp.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Now, what is this **llvm-tblgen: Exec format error** and how do I fix this for a successful build?

I have also raised the issue over at the github repo for **llvm-project**, [issue 62429](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/62429)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix was not even related to LLVM. The real problem was that I had cloned the LLVM project to a shared_folder (a directory shared between guest OS and host OS, under VirtualBox). Now, with Windows 10 host, the symbolic link creation is messed up for the guest OS.

Since LLVM was not throwing an error specific to this, I was unable to detect this. So I tried to use the following command:

```bash
cmake -G "Ninja" \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$(which clang) \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$(which clang++) \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld" \
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;RISCV" \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON \
-DLLVM_PARALLEL_COMPILE_JOBS=2 \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(pwd)/../installed \
-DLLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS=2 \
-DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=OFF \
-DLLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB=OFF \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
-DLLVM_USE_SPLIT_DWARF=ON \
-DLLVM_USE_LINKER=gold \
-DLLVM_OPTIMIZED_TABLEGEN=ON \
-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS='-Wl,-no-keep-memory,-fuse-ld=gold' \
../llvm
```

with `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`, during `ninja -j2` the build system immediately complained that it is not able to create **symbolic links**. Armed with this information I then cloned the project on a path internal to the guest OS and ran the original command (*as in the question above*). This resulted in a successful build.